# Resetting heartbeat timestamps because of huge system clock jump

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am running hazelcast application, and I am getting below error, after keeping my machine in sleep mode/log off for sometime.

```
2021-06-21 14:41:07.854  INFO 8288 --- [cached.thread-7] c.h.i.c.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager 

    : [192.168.181.51]:5701 [APP] [4.2] System clock apparently jumped from 2021-06-21 14:10:28.569 to 2021-06-21 14:41:07.832 since last heartbeat (+1834263 ms)
2021-06-21 14:41:07.855  INFO 8288 --- [cached.thread-9] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection     : [192.168.181.51]:5701 [APP] [4.2] Connection[id=1, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:5702, qualifier=null, endpoint=[127.0.0.1]:5702, alive=false, connectionType=JVM, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Client heartbeat is timed out, closing connection to Connection[id=1, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:5702, qualifier=null, endpoint=[127.0.0.1]:5702, alive=true, connectionType=JVM, planeIndex=-1]. Now: 2021-06-21 14:41:07.833. LastTimePacketReceived: 2021-06-21 14:10:29.314
2021-06-21 14:41:07.915  WARN 8288 --- [cached.thread-7] c.h.i.c.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager     : [192.168.181.51]:5701 [APP] [4.2] Resetting heartbeat timestamps because of huge system clock jump! Clock-Jump: 1834263 ms, Heartbeat-Timeout: 60000 ms
2021-06-21 14:41:08.208  WARN 8288 --- [onMonitorThread] c.h.s.i.o.impl.InvocationMonitor         : [192.168.181.51]:5701 [APP] [4.2] MonitorInvocationsTask delayed 1836451 ms
2021-06-21 14:41:08.213  WARN 8288 --- [onMonitorThread] c.h.s.i.o.impl.InvocationMonitor         : [192.168.181.51]:5701 [APP] [4.2] BroadcastOperationControlTask delayed 1834623 ms
2021-06-21 14:41:08.539  INFO 8288 --- [cached.thread-9] c.h.i.server.tcp.TcpServerConnection     : [192.168.181.51]:5701 [APP] [4.2] Connection[id=2, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:5703, qualifier=null, endpoint=[127.0.0.1]:5703, alive=false, connectionType=JVM, planeIndex=-1] closed. Reason: Client heartbeat is timed out, closing connection to Connection[id=2, /127.0.0.1:5701->/127.0.0.1:5703, qualifier=null, endpoint=[127.0.0.1]:5703, alive=true, connectionType=JVM, planeIndex=-1]. Now: 2021-06-21 14:41:08.539. LastTimePacketReceived: 2021-06-21 14:10:29.949
2021-06-21 14:41:08.551  WARN 8288 --- [ached.thread-36] c.h.i.cluster.impl.MulticastService      : [192.168.181.51]:5701 [APP] [4.2] Sending multicast datagram failed. Exception message saying the operation is not permitted usually means the underlying OS is not able to send packets at a given pace. It can be caused by starting several hazelcast members in parallel when the members send their join message nearly at the same time.

java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: Datagram send failed
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:291) ~[hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.searchForOtherClusters(MulticastJoiner.java:113) [hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.SplitBrainHandler.searchForOtherClusters(SplitBrainHandler.java:75) [hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.SplitBrainHandler.run(SplitBrainHandler.java:42) [hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.executionservice.impl.DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator$DelegateDecorator.run(DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator.java:77) [hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:217) [hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76) [hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102) [hazelcast-all-4.2.jar!/:4.2]
```

My client config is as below:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.setClusterName("abc");
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("localhost");
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().setSmartRouting(true);
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addOutboundPortDefinition("5701-5720");

ClientConnectionStrategyConfig connectionStrategyConfig = clientConfig.getConnectionStrategyConfig();
ConnectionRetryConfig connectionRetryConfig = connectionStrategyConfig.getConnectionRetryConfig();
connectionRetryConfig.setInitialBackoffMillis(1000)
                     .setMaxBackoffMillis(60000)
                     .setMultiplier(2)
                     .setClusterConnectTimeoutMillis(1000)
                     .setJitter(0.2);

HazelcastClient hc = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

Please let me know what wrong configuration am I doing or why this is happening?

Comment: The stacktrace is unrelated to the warning about clock jump. A clock jump is expected when after a computer is wakened from sleep.

The other issue is most likely due to the way how your OS (re-)initializes network interfaces after sleep. 

What operating system is it?

Comment: @JaromirHamala, It's windows. How we can prevent it from stopping?

Comment: I am also not understanding, if server and clients is already connected than how they are disconnecting if machine going log off/sleep they should run in background, because processes are still running , right? Or I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: There are different levels of sleeping, it depends on the exact version of the OS, your hardware capabilities, etc. Regardless of your exact setup the whole point of sleeping is to conserve electrical energy. This means, a CPU is usually in a super-low performance mode, processes are often frozen, etc. When a system with a Hazelcast client is sleeping then from a Hazelcast server perspective it appears as if the client was frozen and never responding hence disconnecting the client is not unexpected.

Comment: It is windows 10, This is some what confusing to me, I have spring boot application and remotely clients are using that application but because client machine goes log off/sleep mode whole functionality stops working but application other parts are working, Is there is any way to prevent this, because after that we have restart whole server which is not good for us. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue for socket based applications. Ideally you disable the sleep / power save mode. You can try using the [SystemParametersInfo API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa):
SystemParametersInfo( SPI_SETPOWEROFFACTIVE, 0, NULL, 0 );

But typically this would be seen as ill behaved since you should disable the Power Off during installation of your application thus requesting permission.